# How to go back previous ViewController from Tab controller of first index in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

From Process ViewController, I am moving to the Tab Bar controller of the first index viewController and coming back to again to process viewController from the tab bar controller.

My issue is When I am coming back to the process viewController and again return back to the tab bar controller, tab bar controller items are not working. Tapped tab bar item menu but nothing works. This issue happens when coming back to the process controller and returning tab bar controller of first index.

Here is the code for the process viewController:

```
  public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {



    let d = getProcessDefData[indexPath.row]

    if let keyVal = d.id {

        print("val key", keyVal)

         A8FlowBuilder(self).loadTaskView(id: keyVal)

    //                let vc = TabBarViewController()
   //                vc.processDefID  = keyVal
  //                navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
  //            navigat

    }


 public func loadTaskView(id: String) {

    let controller = TabBarViewController()
    controller.processDefID = id
    self.taskViewNew?.addChild(controller)
    self.taskViewNew?.view.addSubview(controller.view)
    controller.didMove(toParent: taskViewNew)


  }
```

Here is the code for tab bar controller of the first index:

```
      @objc func callMethod() {

    print("back bar button item pressed")

 //        _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)


 //        navigationController?.popToViewController(ofClass: GetProcessDefinitionsController.self)

 //        let popupVC = GetProcessDefinitionsController()
 //        self.addChild(popupVC)
 //        popupVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
  //        self.view.addSubview(popupVC.view)
  //        popupVC.didMove(toParent: self)
 //        self.tabBarController?.view.removeFromSuperview()


    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      A8FlowBuilder(self).loadProcessdefView()

    }

}
```

Here is my tab bar controller code:

```
func createTabBarController() {


         let firstVC = dashBoardViewController()
        firstVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "dashboard_icon", in: Bundle(for: TabBarViewController.self), compatibleWith: nil), tag: 0)
        firstVC.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0);


        let secondVC = MyTask()
        secondVC.processDefID = processDefID
        secondVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "mytask_icon", in: Bundle(for: TabBarViewController.self), compatibleWith: nil), tag: 1)
        secondVC.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0);


        let thirdVC = settingsViewController()
        thirdVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "settings_icon", in: Bundle(for: TabBarViewController.self), compatibleWith: nil), tag: 2)
        thirdVC.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0);


        let fourthVC = ProfileViewController()
        fourthVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "profile_icon", in: Bundle(for: TabBarViewController.self), compatibleWith: nil), tag: 3)
        fourthVC.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: -5, right: 0);


            let controllerArray = [secondVC, thirdVC]


        tabBarCnt.viewControllers = controllerArray.map{ UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: $0)}
            self.view.addSubview(tabBarCnt.view)


    }
```

Here is the first index of the tab bar controller called **secondVC of MyTask()**

Any help much appreciated pls..

Comment: For issues like this it is a good idea to first check view hierarchy in the state where something is not tappable. Also, is there any reason you are adding tab bar controller as a child controller and not presenting or pushing it?

Comment: my requirement is like that to show process vc then tab bar controller @pckill